Raster calculator substraction does provides wrong values TIN interpolated raster (QGIS)
new here.
The objective is to calculate the volume of contours I made, I've tried with very simple geometries with no luck (half a sphere in this case). I contours I made were TIN interpolated with succes.The problem occurs when I try to substract this raster from an original drone raster. When I try to use the raster calculator the results are way off.

As you can see the band for the substracted layer is incorrect. Not even close!


Are both rasters in the same CRS?

Yes, I have checked.

The numbers look reasonable: you have a raster with values from 21 to 23 and substract from that values between 2.4934 and 36.2899 and get a result with max. value of -0.01262. The (large) min value is the value for NoData cells, not an actual values. So everything seems to be all right.
